# Applying uncertainty principle to energy states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, particle-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Often for this I have heard, the longer the lifetime of the energy state, the uncertainty in the energy state decreases as a result of heisenberg's uncertainty principle. However doesn't that look at uncertainty in time rather than the actual time?

Comment: It does partly, the discussion is quite complicated but it doesn't reflect why the lifetime of the state is a representation of the uncertainty in the time

Comment: From the link talking about $\Delta t$  "*It tells you the approximate amount of time it takes for the expectation value of an observable to change by a standard deviation provided the system is in a pure state.*" In order to get the Energy-time relation that is exactly what you have to define $\Delta t$ to be. If you want to use some other idea of a time interval you can; you will just get some other sort of relation.